# monaco editor based namespace auto complete

Tags: visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

I know monaco editor can auto complete hints according to your custom rules.But I don't know how to auto complete based namespace;

like this:

[image]

Comment: You probably want to find an extension that provides code intelligence for your language. Generic auto-completion is far from being so smart as to understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented alias intellisense support also inside of custom  completion item provider. The goal was to show custom suggestions on 'tags.'

```
const completionItemsProvider = monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('yourLanguageId', {
  triggerCharacters: ['.'],
  provideCompletionItems: (model: monaco.editor.ITextModel, position: monaco.Position, context: monaco.languages.CompletionContext): monaco.languages.ProviderResult<monaco.languages.CompletionList> => {
    let suggestions = [];
    const wordUntilPosition = model.getWordUntilPosition(position);
    // calculate range to pass to suggestions
    const range = {
      startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
      startColumn: wordUntilPosition.startColumn,
      endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
      endColumn: wordUntilPosition.endColumn
    };
    
    const wordAtPosition = model.getWordAtPosition({ lineNumber: position.lineNumber, column: Math.max(position.column - 1, 0) });
    // if word at position before the dot is namespace you want to support
    // in my case it was word tags
    if (wordAtPosition.word === 'tags') {
      // namespace autocomplete suggestions for "tags."
      suggestions = some suggestions;
    }
    else {
      // otherwise I generate another list of suggestions e.g. to show autocompletions for keywords or add custom snippets support
    }
    return { suggestions };

  }
});
```

Suggestions have required properties: label, kind, insertText and range

From API docs:

- **label: string | CompletionItemLabel**
  The label of this completion item. By default this is also the text that is inserted when selecting this completion.
- **kind: CompletionItemKind** The kind of this completion item. Based on the kind an icon is chosen by the editor.
- **insertText: string** A string or snippet that should be inserted in a document when selecting this completion. is used.
- **range: IRange | { insert: IRange; replace: IRange; }** A range of text that should be replaced by this completion item.
  Defaults to a range from the start of the current word to the current position.
  Note: The range must be a single line and it must contain the position at which completion has been requested.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Add additonal d.ts files to the JavaScript language service and change.
// Also change the default compilation options.
// The sample below shows how a class Facts is declared and introduced
// to the system and how the compiler is told to use ES6 (target=2).

// validation settings
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    noSemanticValidation: true,
    noSyntaxValidation: false
});

// compiler options
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES6,
    allowNonTsExtensions: true
});

// extra libraries
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib([
    'namespace test{',
    '/** custom variable',
    ' *',
    ' */',
    'declare interface custom {',
    '/** id html */',
    'id :string;',
    '};',
    '',
    '/** this function does something strange ...',
    ' * @param i my custom variable',
    ' */',
    'declare function MyCustomFunction(i :custom) :void;',
    '}'
].join('\n'), 'filename/facts.d.ts');

var jsCode = [
    ''
].join('\n');

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: jsCode,
    language: "javascript"
});
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/hec12da1/62/