# How to generate monaco completion proposals from C# assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection, monaco-editor

I have a DLL with a set of classes I want to get code completion in Monaco code editor UI. They require them to be in format like this:

```
{
            label: '"lodash"',
            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
            documentation: "The Lodash library exported as Node.js modules.",
            insertText: '"lodash": "*"',
            range: range
}
```

So how to generate Monaco [completion](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/enums/monaco.languages.completionitemkind.html) [proposals](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-completion-provider-example) from C# assembly?

*Notes:*

1. this may be related ["Using Roslyn C# Completion Service programmatically"](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/12/using-roslyn-c-completion-service-programmatically/) yet how to make them work together?
2. If one could generate something like this using reflection:

```js
    'namespace test{',
        'declare interface custom {',
        'id :string;',
        '};',
        '',
        'declare function MyCustomFunction(i :custom) :void;',
        '}'
```

It would solve the problem as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52165983/1973207)

Comment: do you have source code for the assembly?

Comment: yes we do have it

Comment: You can load DLLs using `Assembly.LoadFile` from `System.Reflection` namespace, and then enumerate its classes and methods, is that you want?